# OOP Data Structure to represent an table indexed by two foreign keys

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, .net-4.0

I have been tasked with converting a 'table driven' program to an object oriented one. Everything used to be done by creating large tables in memory, adding and removing rows and columns and parsing everything to strings. It was pretty awful. These tables directly reflected the structure of an underlying database where everything gets stored.

For this problem, I have `Layer` objects, with about 100 properties, and I have `Event` objects, with about 20 more properties. I then have a set of about 10 computed values for each `Layer/Event` pair. These were stored as a third table with a foreign keys pointing to each of the other tables.

I would like to create a proper object oriented class for storing this data and quickly accessing values like you would in a dictionary.

My first thought was to index the results in a dictionary, but I feel its use would be unintuitive:

```
struct EventLayerResult { Decimal sum = 0; Long events = 0; Decimal average; ...}
//Performing Calculations
Dictionary<Tuple<Event,Layer>, EventLayerResult> _EventLayerResults ...;
foreach(Event evt in _Events)
    foreach(Layer lyr in _Layers)
        EventLayerResult elr = newLayerLosses[Tuple.Create(evt, lyr)];
        elr.sum += currentValue;
        elr.events += 1;
        elr.average += elr.Sum/elr.Events;
        etc...
//Using results
EventLayerResult temp = _EventLayerResults.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create(evt, lyr))
someLoss = temp == null ? 0 : temp.expectedLoss;
```

I don't like the idea of having to call Tuple.Create or create new instances of temporary objects every time I create a value. Furthermore, unlike a table, if I want to bind this table in the UI, I can't just bind to Field="Layer", Field="Event", Field="Loss", etc, I have to come up with complex binding expressions which extract `Key.Layer`, `Key.Event`, `Value.Loss`, etc. For that reason, I want to avoid such a data structure.

I could wrap this in an object which lets me easily lookup each value for an Event/Layer combination, but I don't believe I should have to create a 'get' method for each calculated property so that I can use it like this:

```
thisSum = _EventLayerResults.getSum(evt, lyr);
thisEvent = _EventLayerResults.getExpectedLoss(evt, lyr);
```

I also think binding to the full list of results contained in such a structure would be impossible.

My final thought (the one I think is closest to the solution I must use) is a simple collection of objects/structs with all the fields I need to reference:

```
class EventLayerResult { Event oevent; Layer layer; Decimal sum; Long events...}
ObservableCollection<EventLayerResult> _EventLayerResults = ....
_EventLayerResults.Add( new EventLayerResult(){ oevent = evt, layer = lyr } );
```

This is super easy to bind to, but the problem is there's no 'indexing' on this collection. I'm looking at O(Nevts * Nlyrs) time to look up specific Event/Layer results later on unless I start adding on all this extra baggage like a custom wrapper class that monitors the collection Add event and indexes the collection item in a dictionary, etc.

I can't imagine other people go through all of this every time they want to convert a simple table indexed by two foreign keys into an object model. Is there a standard approach or data structure I'm not aware of that can make this sort of data set simple to work with?

Comment: I might be missing something, but can't you just create domain entities, then use an ORM (or roll your own) in the data layer?

Comment: @BobHorn ORM would just produce something like my third example, except with Foreign Keys instead of actual references to the objects they refer to. It wouldn't do anything to solve the problem that the third example has which is the inability to look up values based on their index in less than O(n) time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I've come up with so far is to wrap the Collection and index on the foreign keys using a dictionary, like I suggested in the OP. Seems like a lot of work though:

```
public class EventGroupIDLayerTuple : Tuple<Int32, Layer>
{
    public EventGroupIDLayerTuple(Int32 EventGroupID, Layer Layer) : base(EventGroupID, Layer) { }
    public Int32 EventGroupID { get { return this.Item1; } }
    public Layer Layer { get { return this.Item2; } }
}
public class EventGroupLayerResult
{
    public Int32 EventGroupID { get; set; }
    public Layer Layer { get; set; }
    //Computed Values
    public Decimal Sum { get; set; }
    public Decimal Average { get; set; }
    //...
}

/// <summary>ObservableCollection of computed EventGroup/Layer results that are also indexed
/// in a dictionary for rapid retrieval.</summary>
public class EventGroupLayerResultCollection : ObservableCollection<EventGroupLayerResult>
{
    Dictionary<EventGroupIDLayerTuple, EventGroupLayerResult> _Index = 
        new Dictionary<EventGroupIDLayerTuple,EventGroupLayerResult>();

    public EventGroupLayerResultCollection() : base() { }

    /// <summary>Will return the result for the specified eventGroupID/Layer
    /// combination, or create a new result and return it.</summary>
    public EventGroupLayerResult this[Int32 eventGroupID, Layer layer]
    {
        get
        {
            EventGroupLayerResult retval;
            if( !_Index.TryGetValue(new EventGroupIDLayerTuple(eventGroupID, layer), out retval) )
            {
                retval = new EventGroupLayerResult() { EventGroupID = eventGroupID, Layer = layer };
                this.Add(retval);
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(Int32 eventGroupID, Layer layer)
    {
        return _Index.ContainsKey(new EventGroupIDLayerTuple(eventGroupID, layer));
    }

    #region Index Maintenance
    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        _Index.Clear();
        base.ClearItems();
    }
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, EventGroupLayerResult item)
    {
        _Index.Add(new EventGroupIDLayerTuple(item.EventGroupID, item.Layer), item);
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        _Index.Remove(new EventGroupIDLayerTuple(this[index].EventGroupID, this[index].Layer));
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }
    protected override void SetItem(int index, EventGroupLayerResult item)
    {
        _Index.Remove(new EventGroupIDLayerTuple(this[index].EventGroupID, this[index].Layer));
        _Index.Add(new EventGroupIDLayerTuple(item.EventGroupID, item.Layer), item);
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This code lets me quickly create/access/modify elements in a collection like so:

```
eventGroupLayerResults[evt.GroupID, lyr].Sum += value;
```

While still allowing me to easily bind the collection to the UI.

A better solution would still be appreciated though, seeing as I had to override a bunch of ObservableCollection methods to do it.